# How to decompose an expression into basic forms (e.g. a[[1]] to Part[a, 1], a=1 to Set[a, 1], etc.)?

Tags: expression-manipulation

Is there something I can call in Mathematica to figure out the composition of a given expression?

I want *everything* decomposed to the most basic `f[a, b, c]` format... so `a[[1]]` should get turned into `Part[a, 1]`, `a := 1` should get turned into `SetDelayed[a, 1]`, etc., and any formatting around the text should be displayed as well.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can always look at the `FullForm` of an expression. I'm using `Hold` in my example so that Mathematica doesn't try to evaluate any of the things:

```
Hold[
  {
    f[a,b,c],
    a[[1]],
    a:=1
  }
]//FullForm

(* Hold[List[f[a,b,c],Part[a,1],SetDelayed[a,1]]] *)
```

Comment: I don't think this shows formatting does it? I seem to recall there was a command that showed *everything*, but I can't find it.

Comment: You need to be more specific what you mean by formatting. The front end maintains a *box-form* for each cell that you can see when you press Ctrl+Shift+E. So the `FullForm` is basically the normalized expression where all operators are converted to their full function-call form, but this has nothing to do with how the front end formats or colors the code.

Comment: Hmm, Shift+Ctrl+E seems to be close to what I want... is there a way to call it as a function on an expression?

Comment: Check out `MakeBoxes`

Comment: Ahh! Man it's so close yet so far. So here's where it goes wrong: it doesn't give me an output that I can actually copy paste to get the same expression. It's an outright syntax error for me to try to do that... because it decomposes the input a little *too* much -- even brackets are separated. Sorry I don't know how to better describe what I'm looking for, but hopefully you get a feel for what I mean? I want to be able to decompose an expression into its lowest-level parts while still keeping it an equivalent expression.

Comment: Maybe we can tackle this from the other side: Why do you need this? What will you do with this "low-level representation that contains formatting"?

Comment: Well I'd have a lot of uses for it. One is that I'd be able to send it in a text message to others and make sure when they paste it they get back the exact same expression I had in every way.

Comment: @Mehrdad `InputForm` will reproduce the expression such that the output of evaluating that expression will be the same.

Comment: @Mehrdad Something like that?

 `Import["http://halirutan.github.io/Mathematica-SE-Tools/decode.m"]["http://i.stack.imgur.com/9XqXF.png"]`

(you need to evaluate the whole expression).

Comment: @Edmund: Yes I know, but it neither decomposes it into the constituting commands nor does pasting it result in the same formatting, both of which I wanted.

Comment: @halirutan: Confused... what does `myfunc["with",
 
 "crazy", "line",
 
 
 "breaking"
 ]` mean? Are you asking whether I care about random line breaks being preserved? I suppose not particularly in this case, so we could call it an exception. I don't see it as carrying nearly as much important information as something that was e.g. deliberately bolded.

Comment: @halirutan: It's quite possible what I want can't be done in a single command; that's fine. If there's no better alternatives just let me know and I'm happy to accept your answer. Or if you know of a bunch of commands that achieve different aspects of it feel free to just list them all and I can check them out.